# Draw line in picture box with two mouse clicks in C# windows form

Tags: c#, drawing, mouseevent, line

I need help drawing line on picture box.

I get coordinates for point2 and point2 on mouse click and I drew line between this two coordinates.

What I need to do is to take value for point1 and start drawing the line from that point1, and line should follow my cursor and when I click second time on picture box it should be drawn.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need methods for on click and on mouse move - Look in to those and see how far you get

Comment: Yes, i thought as much, but I don't know how to make line follow my cursor. Have no idea.

Comment: You just redraw/update the line each time you move the mouse..

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - You need to store the points in class level variables, Maybe List<Point>. Do draw only in the Paint event if you want the drawing to __persist__! - There are soo many posts with examples that your question clearly shows a total lack of reasearch!

Comment: Windows Form C#, it is in title

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far

```
// Points p1(x1,y1), p2(x2,y2)
        private Point p1, p2;
        List<Point> p1List = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> p2List = new List<Point>();

        int count = 0;
        // Click 2 times on image to get coordinate values for p1 & p2
        private void pbChooseDirection_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if(count/2 == 0)
            {
                pbChooseDirection.Image = drawingLineImage;
            }

            if (p1.X == 0)
            {
                p1.X = e.X;
                p1.Y = e.Y;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                p2.X = e.X;
                p2.Y = e.Y;
                count++;

                p1List.Add(p1);
                p2List.Add(p2);

                Invalidate();
                // Sets X to 0 and choose p1 again
                p1.X = 0;
            }

        }

private void pbChooseDirection_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 4))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```